# Eclipse diff viewer to use as standalone application

Tags: eclipse, diff

Is that possible to use Eclipse as standalone application
so that I can use it as external diff viewer for Tortoise SVN for example ?
It needs a 'path to executable which takes two command line arguments' file paths to compare.
I would like also reasonable start-up timing.

Answer (score 2):

Most Eclipse operations only work on files in the workspace so this is probably not possible.

In general you have to write a 'headless' (no GUI) Eclipse RCP to use Eclipse plugins. This ensures that the Eclipse OSGi plugin system and the workspace are initialized properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create Eclipse as standalone application.

Creating **Eclipse RCP application** is one of the solutions. 
You can pass file paths to compare via the command line to an Eclipse RCP application. Example:

```
String[] args = Platform.getCommandLineArgs();
```